# Why is there a "libs" folder in my application in Android?

Tags: android, android-library

I cannot understand the purpose of the `libs` folder in the application under Android.

Comment: For adding external jar libraries, such as the support library.

Comment: @null that escalated quickly.

Answer (score 3):

It is where all the libraries referenced by your application are stored

Answer (score 0):

If you use 3rd party libraries, you will add the jars to the *libs* folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Android command line to create your project, it'll default to libs/. It turns out that the Android Ant tasks are set to look in libs/ by default.

See `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:`

```
<property name="jar.libs.dir" value="libs" />
```

If you just care about Eclipse, you can use whatever you want.
It contain all the **libraries referenced by your application** are stored

In newer revisions of ADT (revision 17 onwards), the Ant-based build system and the Eclipse plug-in are aligned so that they behave the same way. This means, by default, only the jars that are present in the libs folder are included in the final apk file. These jars would automatically appear under "Android Dependencies" in your Eclipse project.

For more details please refer here. http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following from the android developer site:

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationProjects

libs/
Contains private libraries.

You can find a lot of additional helpful information there as a new developer!

Answer (score 0):

Because Google says we should add the jars to /libs folder and the /lib folder is used for shared library files that executables make use of.